# My app rejected due to audio in the UIBackgroundModes key

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

my application rejected due to this issue :

> Your app declares support for audio in the UIBackgroundModes key in
>   your Info.plist, but we were unable to play any audible content when
>   the app was running in the background.

The fun part of this rejection is my app approved in version 1  ! and now in version 1.1 they reject due to this problem! I have a built in music player and when you play a song, the song will continue playing in the background , I even send a video clip to claim my explanation, But the reviewer still rejects my app !!!!

What is the solution ? If I remove `the App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay` from Plist music will not play in background !

This is the part of code which enable music playing in the background :

```
//Play music when it's on BG
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        print("AVAudioSession is Active")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

Comment: Have you considered assuming the approver might not be dumb, and may indeed not have been successful playing content using your app? Could there be any reason - say, the user not being logged in to some service, or a bug - why playing content in the background might have gone wrong? Have you tested the application on various devices and been successful playing sound in the background on all of them?

Comment: Looks more like they experienced a bug.  According to them they couldn't get anything to play.  Because of that they'd either like you to fix that or remove the requirement from the plist.

Comment: But maybe the approver ran into a set of circumstances where it didn't work?

Comment: I just appeal app rejection and they approved the application !!! , some times  the reviewers are .... !

Comment: OK, fair enough. :) Seems you were right then.